# Get list of Students who scored "x" marks Java8 List<Student> to Map<Marks,List<Name>> with limit to number of Names

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I want to convert list of objects to `Map<K,List<V>>`, but the overall items in the list is limited. Limit = 1024
There are 2 stages for this problem :

```
Student {
    name: String
    marks: Long
}
```

Same name multiple marks possible. Need to add marks in that case.
Expected results for stage 1 - Student name and total marks

```
originalStudentList = List<Student>
intermediateMap = Map <String, Long>
newExpectedMap Map<Long, List<String>
```

Stage 1:

```
originalStudentList.stream()
.collect(Collectors.toConcurrentMap(Student::getName,
                Student::getMarks, (marks1, marks2) -> marks1+marks2));
```

The output of this would be -

```
originalStudentList = [{"a",3},{"b",2},{"c",3},{"d",2},{"a",2},{"f",7},{"e",3}];

intermediateMap = [{"a",5},{"b",2},{"c",3},{"d",2},{"f",7},{"e",3}];
```

Stage 2:
Now, lets say I want map of only top 5 students

```
intermediateMap.entrySet()
            .stream
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue,
                Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())));
```

With the above code I would get the below map

```
newExpectedMap = [{7,{"f"}},{5,{"a"}},{3,{"c","e"}},{2,{"b","d"}}]
```

But I want to limit the number of items in string to 5 - so instead I want

```
newExpectedMap = [{7,{"f"}},{5,{"a"}},{3,{"c","e"}},{2,{"b"}}]
```

Note: I am ok with it removing either b or d but it has to be from the last entries. If the limit is 3 then it would remove from key:3

I am stuck at Stage 2 - but I am ok to modify the entire flow if that is something which would make it easy.

Comment: I can do it the traditional way - using a for loop, but I was looking for something using java8 and lambda. Let me know what additional information you need to make it clear

Comment: for example your `originalMap` does _not_ have `{"5","a"}`, but you _do_ have it in the `newExpectedMap`; it seems like you want to collect your `originalMap` with grouping _and_ limiting the total number of values to a certain number - removing values from the "least" keys

Comment: ... and your `originalMap` has two times "a" - you do know you can't have that right?

Comment: Sorry my bad! I tried to simplify this. Let me edit the question

Comment: @Eugene - Hope this helps!

Comment: you still have two "a" as key in a map.

Comment: But that is in my originalList of Students - Its not a map. The intermediate map just has single "a"

Comment: either way - after the perform your Step1; Step2 is a lot better and easier performed with a plain loop - that is because you need to maintain state of how many values you put into the resulting map; maintaining state for stream operations could be done, but not recommended. use a loop!

Comment: Cool - If the recommendation is to avoid streams, then I can go ahead with traditional for loop :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can not achieve this in one step, but using two:

```
Map<Long, List<String>> top5 = students.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getName, Collectors.summingLong(Student::getMarks)))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Long>comparingByValue().reversed())
        .limit(5)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue, LinkedHashMap::new,
                Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())));
```

The first part is the same as your first stage the you sort the result by value and limit the result list to `5` the you can collect the results again. If you want the items descending in you map use a `LinkedHashMap` like I did above.

The result will be this:

```
{7=[f], 5=[a], 3=[c, e], 2=[b]}
```

Comment: Actually this is working. I am getting the expected results, but I cant understand how! Specially the limit part. How is limit ensuring the overall value list is within 5?

Comment: @meso Because you sort the entries descending before. `limit` then takes the first 5 values, so the 5 entries with the highest values.

Comment: Oh I think I get it now! So intermediateMap would be this - 
[{"f",7},{"a",5},{"c",3},{"e",3},{"b",2},{"d",2}]

I mean after the sort :) and then applying limit would result in [{"f",7},{"a",5},{"c",3},{"e",3},{"b",2}]

Comment: It would be `[f=7, a=5, c=3, e=3, b=2]`. It has only 5 entries, so the final result also has only 5 students.

Comment: I  tried it without a downstream collector: `Collectors.toMap(Entry::getValue, entry -> List.of(entry.getKey()), (l, r) -> Stream.concat(l.stream(), r.stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toList()), LinkedHashMap::new)`. But the downstream collector has the advantage to create only one instance of a `List` whereas my approach is creating _n_ intermediate `List` instances. Thus I  would prefer you solution too.